# Phpunit for legacy PHP 5.1?

Tags: php, phpunit, refactoring, legacy-code

I'm doing some refactoring work, and I really need a phpunit library to start some testing (or it will be very annoying and slow process). So i'm trying to find a Phpunit version that runs with Php 5.1.

Any help with this or any recommendation for my case?

Answer (score 0):

PHPUnit 3.4, released six years ago, was the last version to support PHP 5.1.

Comment: Thanks! I got the package. Is it possible to use just like that or I need other dependencies for this? Is there something to ease this?

Comment: You will need dependencies. There is no easy way to install them because back when PHPUnit 3.4 was current the PEAR Installer was the only supported way of installing PHPUnit. And for quite some time these PEAR packages are no longer available.